# How does one add arbitrary text to a grid view?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, adminhtml, grid

I'd like to be able to add arbitrary text to grid view such as instructions or reminders above the grid and pagination controls or a footnote below the table. What is the best method for doing this? One way might be to create a custom template (*e.g.*, in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mymodule/customgrid.phtml`) and then add an entry in the layout XML (*e.g.*, `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml`).

Am I barking up the right tree? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Just adding a Child Block

Checked the template. In frontent there are many blocks to do such things, but nor in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml` neither in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml` is any `getChildHtml` or something like to hook into.

## Changing the Template

Changing the template is an easy way to achieve what you want.

## Message Block

If it is enough for your purpose, you can just add a message:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

I didn't check what `<?php if($this->canDisplayContainer()): ?>` does, because the message is only shown in the `else`, but I think this is a way to go.